# docker - cannot connect to exposed port on container using host ip

Tags: docker

Apologies if this obvious - I can't seem to figure this out.
I have a docker container with ports 8112 exposed to the host. Docker ps shows:
'
 0.0.0.0:8112->8112/tcp
'

From the host, I can successfully connect to the port using localhost:
'
curl localhost:8112 **This works
'

From the host or remote machine, I cannot connect via ip:
'
curl 192.168.0.5:8112  **This fails - just hangs and eventually timeouts
'

I'm not sure how to diagnose from here - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `tcpdump` is the way to diagnose this, and perhaps netfilter's `TRACE` target.

Comment: Thank you - will read up on that. Is there anything I should be looking for specifically?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to [known limitations of Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds).

From the link: "Per-container IP addressing is not possible"

Link is for Mac, as that is what I use, but I think there may be a similar limitation with Docker for Windows.

This is likely why you are able to access the container from localhost, but not by its IP.

EDIT: This all applies to connecting to the container from the host, if you want to connect to it remotely there are a bunch of other factors like firewalls that have nothing to do with Docker and might prevent you from accessing.